# How to stop Excel changing dates to numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-formatting

When having to compile the text from different cells, I am getting issue with dates converted to numbers. I have 3 cells  with patient number, kit number and date (formatted to dd-mmm-yyyy). Tried different formatting and formulas but still cannot get the result 1_1234_26-JUL-2021, the dates keep changing to numbers.

Answer (score 4):

It's not entirely clear, but it seems like you have a formula like this:

```
=A2&"_"&B2&"_"&C2
```

... where A2 is a patient number, B2 is a kit number, and C2 is a date. You expect C2 to be pulled in with the same formatting but it's showing up as a number, probably 44403 if you're on Windows and the date is 26-JUL-2021. This is because Excel treats dates (and times) as numbers. For windows, it counts the days from 01-JAN-1900. If you reference a date in a formula, it uses the number. There's a way to force it to whatever format you want, though:

```
=A2&"_"&B2&"_"&UPPER(TEXT(C2,"dd-mmm-yyyy"))
```

[TEXT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) formats a number as desired and returns the result as a string. [UPPER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/upper-function-c11f29b3-d1a3-4537-8df6-04d0049963d6) will make it return `JUL` instead of `Jul`.

Comment: Additional note; the formatting codes for `TEXT()` are the same ones used in the "Format Cell" dialog, which is brought up by `CTRL`+`1` in Excel and 'Libre Office Calc'

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c